# Avoiding NPM global install using .bash_profile and "postinstall" script

Tags: node.js, bash, gulp

NPM philosophy, for better or worse, is to have all necessary dependencies for a project to be locally installed, in `./node_modules`, and for package.json to reflect all necessary deps.

I have a library, that would typically benefit from both global installation and local installation, similar to Gulp, Mocha, etc.

One of the most insiduous problems with the above, is that the global and local versions might differ, causing compatibility issues for a given project.

It occurred to me that we could avoid this problem, by creating an alias in `.bash_profile`, something like this:

```
# bash psuedocode 
* alias gulp='using current working directory, find the locally installed gulp and run that'
```

My library is not Gulp, but you get the idea. I know a lot of devs don't like the idea of 3rd parties writing to their bash_profiles, but I think that is a bit anal-retentive, considering doing something like this has zero outside effects (TMK).

So I have three questions:

> (1) Is this a good idea?
>
> (2) Are there any projects that do something similar and how?
>
> (3) I an not great with bash scripting, how do you write a bash script
>   that can recursively look for node_modules/.bin/gulp if you the dev
>   runs the gulp command from a directory that is within the project
>   but not in the root?

My thinking was that as a postinstall script to

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

we would run a script that

1. added the above line* to the .bash_profile
2. in that line, we would point to a script stored under /Users/you/.gulp that would be responsible for locating the locally installed gulp.

This way we save the need for global installations of modules, when they are only used for command line convenience, as well as alleviating the problem of differing package versions.

Comment: One issue that might bite you is that many people use `.profile` rather than `.bash_profile`.  `.profile` is only used if `.bash_profile` is not present, so everything would be fine until your product suddenly introduced a new file - `.bash_profile`.  Then your file would be executed, but all the goodness that was in the user's `.profile` would not.  Check,   there are sites with both!  Korn shell uses `.profile`, I'm not sure about `dash` and `zsh` - you should investigate those too - not everyone uses bash, you might also check for `.login` (csh, and bash if `.profile` is not present).

Comment: On the general principle of using aliases - in my opinion they are generally not a good idea for anything but command-line shortcuts (scripts don't use them unless an option is set, and they can be a support nightmare).  Functions are preferred.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by functions are preferred?

Comment: functions are preferred over aliases.  They are far more powerful and easier to debug.

Comment: do you hv a link to what functions are? not just for me, for any reader who doesn't know what you are talking about - from a bash newb

Comment: are functions in bash scripts global in the same way that aliases are...?

Comment: What do you mean by "global"?   They can be exported, and they can be used anywhere within a script, or on the command-line.  They can be read in from external files (using `source` or `.`).  You can also locally scope variables (using `local`).  They are an important part of bash programming, see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html (Google "bash functions").

Comment: It is my personal opinion that there is no good reason to global install a module.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067055/avoiding-npm-global-install-using-bash-profile-and-postinstall-script/40069979#40069979) with info about functions in bash with examples of some of my own functions, how to write them, how to install them and how to use them. See below.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067055/avoiding-npm-global-install-using-bash-profile-and-postinstall-script/40069979#40069979) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no accepted answer. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to make sure they are good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go through your 3 questions one by one:

> (1) Is this a good idea?

**No.** Changing user's private files automatically is **never** a good idea and I see several things that can go horribly wrong if you do that - from a pure annoyance of users having to clean after your programs, to breaking user's system config, to serious security problems.

> (2) Are there any projects that do something similar and how?

I hope not. I would never run any program that messes with my `.bash_profile` - even though I don't have it. I have `.profile` and `.bashrc`. And that's another problem for you - are you sure you even know what to edit? What if I use `dash` which I use sometimes, or `zsh` or some other shell?

> (3) I an not great with bash scripting, how do you write a bash script that can recursively look for node_modules/.bin/gulp if you the dev runs the gulp command from a directory that is within the project but not in the root?

If you are not great with bash scripting then your **definitely** should not edit user's private files automatically.

What you **can** do is to provide a certain alias or bash function in a separate file **for user's convenience** and explain how users can source your file inside of their `.bashrc` **if they want to**.

But never make that decision for them. If anything goes wrong this can even have legal consequences for you.

### Examples of functions

Answering your questions posted in the comments, I'll add few words on how functions work in Bash.

In [my collection of script on GitHub](https://github.com/rsp/scripts) I have few functions with instructions on [how to install them](https://github.com/rsp/scripts#installing-functions) and [how to use them](https://github.com/rsp/scripts#functions). Their source code is available [here](https://github.com/rsp/scripts/blob/master/ok-functions.md).

An example function in that collection is `ok` - this is its source code:

```
ok() {
  # prints OK or ERROR and exit status of previous command
  s=$?
  if [[ $s = 0 ]]; then
    echo OK
  else
    echo ERROR: $s
  fi
}
```

You can download it (with some other related functions) from:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rsp/scripts/master/ok-functions

If you save it as `~/ok-functions` then you can either run:

```
source ~/ok-functions
```

to have them available in that session, or you can put that line in `.profile` or `.bashrc` to have it available after every login. You can use it as if it was a normal command or program like this:

```
ls /bin; ok
ls /binn; ok
```

### Working example of preventing global install

I wrote a Bash function that does what you are trying to do - it stops global installation of a certain module - called `modname` in this example. Save it to some file - e.g. to `~/no-global-restricted-module` - of course you can change the `restricted-module` name in `n` and the warning message in `w` to suit your needs:

```
npm() {
  n=restricted-module
  w="Please don't install $n globally - see: http://example.com/"
  i=0
  g=0
  m=0
  for a in "$@"; do
    case $a in
      i|install)
        i=1;;
      -g|--global)
        g=1;;
      $n)
        m=1;;
    esac
  done
  if (( $i == 1 && $g == 1 && $m == 1 )); then
    echo $w >&2
    return 1
  else
    `which npm` "$@"
  fi
}
```

And then add this line to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
source ~/no-global-restricted-module
```

Now when you log in again, or when you open a new terminal window, you can try running this in your command line:

```
npm install --global restricted-module
```

You should see a warning and no installation will be started. If you enter some other module name or you omit the `--global` switch then the installation should proceed as usual. This also works with the shortcuts of `i` instead of `install` and `-g` instead of `--global`.

This is pretty much what you are trying to do. You can include that function in your documentation with instructions on how to use it. I am hereby releasing it under the terms of the MIT license so you can use it freely. I published it on GitHub with some more options for configuration and information on how to use it, see:

- https://github.com/rsp/npm-no-global-install

### See also

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/make-a-sound-once-process-is-complete/604116#604116) for a much better explanation of writing, installing and using Bash functions on the example of playing various sounds in the terminal.

Comment: NVM writes to user's bash_profile, and that is a very very popular package

Comment: but I think you're right. My plan is to have them do the global install, and then recommend that they add the line to their .bash_profile / .bashrc. That line of bash code will help users make things work with NVM better.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I updated this answer again - this time with a working example of a Bash function that blocks global npm installation of one module.