# Any way to restrict global package installation?

Tags: windows, npm, teamcity, npm-install

We have a TeamCity build server on Windows, and we're having a problem with teams trying to install different versions of global packages.

I want to restrict global package install, but i'm drawing a blank on any info on this.  I've already removed ACL's on the .npmrc because people were messing with proxy and registry global settings.  I need a way to restrict global package installation as well.

Is it as simple as removing write access to the node_packages folder under ~/AppData/Roaming/npm/?

Comment: I think this is duplicate man, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068151/preventing-global-installations-of-an-npm-package

Comment: @MichaelWarner - no, that post is about writing a module that can't be installed globally, not preventing users in general from installing modules globally.